# What event or binding will allow me to disable the Add record button the moment edits begin?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, events, binding

My WPF window binds directly to an Entity Framework data context (CollectionViewSource). Users begin editing immediately once a record is found. **The moment the form is dirty I'd like to disable the Add button and enable the Save and Undo buttons.** Is there a simple way to do this using binding or an event?

I'm not using MVVM. I use Entity Framework database first and the EF designer. I'm hoping to avoid adding code for every field. The database is quite large.

Comment: It depends on how your Add Button works. If it only goes to a Click event in the code behind, you could probably use the PreviewKeyDown or TextInput event to disable/enable your buttons. If it goes to a Command in a ViewModel, you can probably tie the ICommand.CanExecute with the EntityState. Just remember that some controls (like TextBoxes) default to only changing the source property when the control loses focus, so you may need to change some of your bindings to `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` if you want an instant change

Comment: My Add button has a click event which calls an AddNewRecord method. I like the idea of using PreviewKeyDown or TextInput.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without events if you'd like.  And you can leverage the power of `DataBinding` without going so far as MVVM.  The example below demonstrates, in a very simple way, how you can accomplish this.  If your entity classes don't already have an IsDirty property (it has been a while since I've used database-first EF), you could add the property with a partial class.

XAML:

```
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Name:" Margin="10"/>
      <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

      <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsDirty}" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsDirty}" Click="Cancel_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsClean}"/>
      </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

A test Entity class:

```
public class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private bool _isDirty = false;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if(!IsDirty)
                IsDirty = (value != _name);

            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");               
        }
    }

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get{ return _isDirty; }
        set{
            _isDirty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsDirty");
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsClean");
        }
    }

    public bool IsClean
    {
        get { return !_isDirty; }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And the code behind for the window:

```
namespace Test
{
  public partial class EditTesting : Window
  {
    private Entity _myEntity;

    public EditTesting()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      _myEntity = new Entity();
      this.DataContext = _myEntity;
    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      _myEntity.Name = string.Empty;
      _myEntity.IsDirty = false;
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: My app already has hundreds of fields and is growing. Modifying every EF property/field would become extremely tedious. I was hoping something like this approach was already built in to .Net. It would make this approach much simpler. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @DeveloperDan - understood.  I had thought EF provided implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` and dirty tracking, but if not, then certainly a big change.  In the future, you may want to consider T4 templates so that you can add support for `INotifyPropertyChanged` and start taking advantage of DataBinding, which is a huge part of WPF.  This answer demonstrates how to add INotifyPropertyChanged to your DBContext: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/4bf1b484-eeef-4b1d-9b2c-ce4d9ce12367/